# How to fetch git repository on web server

Tags: git

A friend of me have upload .git folder on his web server.
I do not have rights to see directory index, but i can download .git/index and other files (i need to know file names i want to download).

Is there a way to fetch all files with a command like git clone in this case ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're going to push to the repo one has to setup `post-update` hook at the server. See the section "Dumb HTTP" at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols
2. If you not gonna push you still need to run `git update-server-info` on the server and check that the command updated the file `.git/info/refs`. See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols

After that you probably can clone.